# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm building a web app on Spring MVC framework and using thymeleaf as my template engine.

I had a working app before adding a new REST controller. An IOException is now thrown

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

```
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getAlias(FileResource.java:195)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.checkAlias(ContextHandler.java:1599)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.getResource(ContextHandler.java:1583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.getResource(WebAppContext.java:360)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.getResource(JettyWebAppContext.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext$Context.getResource(WebAppContext.java:1325)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver.isResourceUnderLocation(PathResourceResolver.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver.checkResource(PathResourceResolver.java:148)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver.getResource(PathResourceResolver.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver.getResource(PathResourceResolver.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver.resolveResourceInternal(PathResourceResolver.java:76)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.AbstractResourceResolver.resolveResource(AbstractResourceResolver.java:46)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultResourceResolverChain.resolveResource(DefaultResourceResolverChain.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.getResource(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:271)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It's only happening when the browser attempts to fetch the css, js or any other static resources from my taoConnection-servlet.xml. The same occurs on both my jetty and tomcat7 deployments. After a couple of hours searching I can't find any similar problem.

**edit:** I'm making the call to the /account request mapping but it happens for all request mapping that access static resources. If I try to access the resources directly in the browser e.g. http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css or http://localhost:8080/js/sb-admin-2.js the exception is thrown.

Alternatively if I try to access a fake resource e.g. http://localhost:8080/js/fake.js I still get a standard http 404 which is expected but the IOException is not thrown.

**Project structure**

```
-src
 -main
  -java
   -*controller
    -MainController.java
    -RestAccountController.java
  -resources
   -META-INF
    -spring
     -applicationContext.xml
  -webapp
   -css
   -font-awesome-4.1.0
   -js
   -less
   -pages
   -WEB-INF
    -taoConnection-servlet.xml
    -web.xml
```

**taoConnection-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.quadrimular.nts.results.connection.*" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.quadrimular.nts.results.connection" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/**" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/**" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/font-awesome-4.1.0/**" location="/font-awesome-4.1.0/**" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/pages/**" />

    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

     <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"></bean>
</beans>
```

**MainController.java**

```
package com.quadrimular.nts.results.connection.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.quadrimular.fyfe.fulfillment.service.AccountService;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllaccounts(ModelMap model){
        try{
            model.addAttribute("accountList", accountService.getAllAccounts());
        }catch(Exception e){
            model.addAttribute("error", true);
            model.addAttribute("errMsg", e.getMessage());
        }

        return "account";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String main(ModelMap model){
        return "main";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String addAccount(ModelMap model){
        return "account";
    }
}
```

**RestAccountController.java**

```
package com.quadrimular.nts.results.connection.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.quadrimular.fyfe.fulfillment.Account;
import com.quadrimular.fyfe.fulfillment.service.AccountService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class RestAccountController {

    AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    public RestAccountController(AccountService accountService){
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/account", method= RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List<Account> getAllAccounts(){
        List<Account> accounts = accountService.getAllAccounts();
        return accounts;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/account", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Account addAccount(@RequestBody Account act) throws Exception{
            return accountService.addAccount(act);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleException(Exception e) {
        return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>taoConnection</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>taoConnection</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: you need post your project structure and maybe also the requestmapping you are calling

Comment: I've updated the question with requested information and some additional clarification. I'm really lost as to what caused this to develop. There was no configuration change that I can remember. Appreciate your time.

Comment: please also the web.xml

Comment: web.xml added to the end of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/font-awesome-4.1.0/**" location="/font-awesome-4.1.0/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/pages/" />
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  I wonder if you could explain to me why a very similar project (in fact the starting point for this one) has the location="/css/**" and works as expected, full access to all static resources?
Thanks for the solution I just don’t understand why it sorted the problem or what the problem was in the first place.

Comment: @RobertField added `**` back and restart your server with DEBUG enabled, spring will tell you the problem